# Как добавить данные в ячейку sqllite python

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть база данных. Мне нужно найти строку по уникальному id и ДОБАВИТЬ(уже к существующей) информацию в ячейку по определенному столбцу.

```
(f"INSERT INTO users(id = {id}) VALUES(friends=?)", (friendid,))
```

я думал что такая строка может выполнить задачу, но это не так.
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне правильно построить запрос.

Comment: У Вас беда с терминологией - так что Вас просто не понимают. Покажите на примере - вот так было (2-3 строки), вот нужный id, вот так должно стать.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы обновить уже существующую запись по id, то необходимо использовать оператор UPDATE.

Пример:

```
UPDATE users SET name = 'Имя' WHERE id = '1';
```

Comment: мне нужно добавить уже к существующей.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то всё верно. Пример запроса через оператор UPDATE: 
UPDATE users 
SET name = 'Имя' 
WHERE id = '1'

В SET указываете через переменную столбцы, которые необходимо обновить, а в WHERE указываете id пользователя, стобцы которого необходимо обновить. Подробнее здесь: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Проверил. Новая запись удаляет прошлую

Comment: @boris *Новая запись удаляет прошлую* Не удаляет, а изменяет.